# How do I remove a net from a dodo without killing it?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

So, I was attempting to capture a player from an enemy tribe who was raiding my tribe's base in Ark. I fired a net projectile from my harpoon gun, but missed and hit one of our dodos. You have to use a sharp weapon to remove a net from a captured creature, but even the stone hatchet, the weakest sharp weapon I know of, will kill the dodo before freeing it. Is it possible to free this dodo without killing it (other than waiting for the net to break and fall off on its own, I know that works but I dont want to wait that long), and if so, how?